# How to rename a nested file in visual studio extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have nested files like this

[image]

If i want to rename the file "Class1.v7_1_1.cs", I didn't get the rename option in visual studio. So either i need to manually edit the proj file or do a custom extension.

In case of custom extension how to give rename facility like this

[image]

and rename the file ?

I need to develop a custom extension which should do renaming as just like how Visual Studio renames the other non-nested files.

**My Solution**

My current solution is showing a window on right click of the selected file which needs to be renamed. In the window let the user enters the new file name and do the file renaming in the extension. But I don't know how to do the inline renaming as shown above.

Please help me this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this Mads' extension? (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ebde8fb-26d8-4374-a0eb-1e4e2665070c/view/Discussions/2).  I tried this in VS2017 where code was in version control.  It changed the state to add file on the renamed which wasn't ideal but not convinced it worked.  I unnested the files then renamed, then renested.  Not ideal but still.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the project file directly.

Search for

```
<Compile Include="Class1.v7_1_0.cs">
```

and correct it to

```
<Compile Include="Class1.v7_1_1.cs">
```